# css not being applied to a nested class

Tags: css

I have this structure...

```
<body>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="login-welcome">
                <h3 class="welcome">
                <form class="form-login">
```

I'm able to apply css to `login-welcome` and `welcome` but not to `form-login`.

In Chrome Debugger, I don't see the styles I've set.  These are the relevant styles...

```
.login-welcome {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 40%;
    display: block;
}

.welcome {
    font-weight: 600px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #653487;
}​

.form-login {
    padding-top: 500px;
}
```

In debugger, I can adjust the same padding setting by adjusting `element.style` so I figured using `form .form-login` or `.form-login` would work but the classes I've tried has not applied any formatting to the class.  Any reason why that would be the case?

Comment: Are you able to throw this into a working codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: I'll try to decouple it from the main website

Comment: Or link the site, can look at the source code

Comment: I realized just now that I could just inspect the html and get what I needed - thought I had to decouple it from the main site / Flask.  Anyway, from that I noticed the issue in jsfiddle. It's what evil_skunk mentioned.  So much time wasted hah

Comment: It happens to us all. Was wracking my brain last week, couldn't figure out why active class was applying to home page but none of the others. Wrote a question included code, set up a fiddle, linked site. About 20 minutes and a guy goes.. Uh.. You didn't include the js link in your other web pages.. Haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I copy your css to chrome, there is some weird character right after the closing `}` of `.welcome`

`&#8203;`
it seems like it's stopping chrome from interpreting the next css lines

When you remove this character the following css selectors (e.g. `.form-login {`) are evaluated again and will be applied to your form element - everything should work then

Comment: hmm I don't see that. I pasted in the text into Notepad++ and set it to show all symbols.  All I see are LF symbols

Comment: change encoding to ANSI in notepad++ and you will see it :)

Comment: This was it. I didn't see the symbol till I dropped it into jsfiddle and saw something odd. I didn't check ANSI either. I'll keep this in mind. I thought Visual Studio Code set to Unix would address this but I guess I need to see be mindful of it in Windows.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```css
div.login-welcome .welcome{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="page-content">
    <div class="login-welcome">
      Im not affected
      <h3 class="welcome">Some heading text</h3>
      <form class="form-login">
        some form text
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works as follows: `div.login-welcome .welcome` is a `CSS` selector which applies styles for element which have a `welcome` class and a `<div>` parent elements which have the class login-welcome.

Hopefully this was helpful.

Comment: Wouldn't it affect parent welcome as welcome as well?  I want to adjust padding of only `form-login`

Comment: This will only affect the <h3> element as you can see in my updated example

Answer (score 0):

Your code works:

```css
.login-welcome {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 40%;
    display: block;
}

.welcome {
    font-weight: 600px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #653487;
}

.form-login {
    padding-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="login-welcome">
        <h3 class="welcome">Welcome header</h3>
        <form class="form-login">
          <input type="text">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

look at this fiddle: https://jsbin.com/segiqoyoci/edit?html,css,output